# Extracting specific text from a text file in python

Tags: python, search, text, extract

I have a big text file, let say :

`random text Blabla blabla <aaa@gmail.com> bliblibli vlavlavla "bbb@hotmail.com" kakaka lolol <ccc@outlook.su.org> mamama pfdsfsdf random text`

And I want to read it and extract all emails from it, and then stock them into an array.

The emails are always contained between <> or between "". And they always contains an @. But they dont always end with a .com. Sometimes they end with many dots (like the example of .su.org).

How can I do that in Python please ?

I tried this :

```
filepath = 'C://PROGRAMING//Outlook//test1.CSV'
with open(filepath) as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    print(lines)
```

It show all the text, but in between I need to add something to take only the informations I want (the emails) and stock them into an array.

Answer (score -1):

You could use RegEx to extract your emails from your files; see this documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

To find the emails, you can search for every character ( . ) between < or ":

`import re`

`re.search('<|".*>|"', lines)`

I'll let you test that solution.

Comment: Thank you for the RegEx tip ! I found how to do it : '''import numpy as np
import re

filepath = 'C://PROGRAMING//Outlook//test1.CSV'

with open(filepath) as file:
    lines = file.read()
    email_ids = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', lines)
    email_ids = list(set(email_ids))
    email_ids = np.array(email_ids)
    np.savetxt('emails1.txt', email_ids, delimiter='  ', comments='', fmt='%s')'''